# Git Branches without Pulling

Tags: git

I have 4 projects that are all related to a single software package. One of those 4 projects can be considered the "pristine" which gets a lot of attention and updates.

I have this as the master branch.

What I want to do now, is to make the other 3 projects act as a branch, "mutation" branches, which share some structure but not all with the master branch.

How can I do this?

So far I've been trying to go to one of the project mutated directories and do the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin [...]
it checkout -b mutation1
```

But I get this weird message:

```
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

I need to push without pulling the files from the master to the mutated projects.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correctly, you have some code, and want to push this as a branch to an existing git repository?

As you cannot branch in an empty repository, first commit your code, and then create the branch:

```
git branch mutation1
```

Check it out and delete the master:

```
git checkout mutation1
git branch -d master
```

And then push it:

```
git push origin mutation1
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't create a branch after `git init` ~

Comment: Ah, I see, the repository must not be empty, let me update my answer.